# Simplifying a two-parameter anonymous function in Elm

Tags: elm, function-composition

In Elm, if I have an anonymous function

```
(\f x -> f x)
```

I can simplify it to

```
(<|)
```

Can the same be done for a two-parameter function where the parameters are arguments to another function?

```
(\x y -> f x y |> g)
```

I thought I could simply use

```
(f |> g)
```

but the compiler complains about the types.

Specifically, in one of the cases for my `update` function, I have something like this:

```
let
  msgNames = [Foo, Bar]

  values = ["f", "b"] // These values are actually derived
                      // by a more complicated operation

  model_ = List.map2 (<|) msgNames values
               |> List.foldl (\msg mod -> update msg mod |> Tuple.first)
                      model
in
  ( model_, Cmd.none )
```

I am trying to simplify the anonymous function argument to `List.foldl` to something like `(update |> Tuple.first)`, but I get the following error from the compiler:

```
The right side of (|>) is causing a type mismatch.

159|                                      update |> Tuple.first)
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
(|>) is expecting the right side to be a:

    (Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )) -> a

But the right side is:

    (( Model, Cmd Msg )) -> Model
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can follow a few steps to simplify:

```elm
(\x y -> f x y |> g)
... can be written as
(\x y -> g (f x y))
... can be written as
(\x -> g << f x)
```

One more step and things get a little more confusing:

```elm
(((<<) g) << f)
```

This matches what you get from [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io) (which is Haskell where function composition is done using the `.` operator):

```elm
(g .) . f
```

If you are trying to improve readability, you might just want to make your own infix function:

```elm
infixr 9 <<<
(<<<) : (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> d)
(<<<) g f x y =
    g (f x y)
```

And now you can use it like this:

```elm
(g <<< f)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. I agree that `(((<<) g) << f)` is not overly readable and may not be an improvement over the simple anonymous function.